# JPA Transactions on Informix

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, informix

I need to make an update on a table using JPA 2.0 with EclipseLink 3.0 on a Java SE 7.0 environment, using Non-Transactional Informix DB v. 11.50, the persistence.xml is:

```
<persistence-unit name="pp_pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>...</class>
    <class>...</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                  value="jdbc:informix-sqli://10.191.78.230:40494/ptpr:informixserver=online_ptpr"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="test"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="test"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And when i try to make an update I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:1776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeUpdate(EJBQueryImpl.java:533)
```

Then i try to solve the error with the following:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
// Update query
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

And now i get the following error:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Transactions not supported
Error Code: -79744
Exception in thread "main" Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Transactions not supported
Error Code: -79744
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="update tg_proteccion_cv
set i_eq_validados=?,
    i_eq_a_protegidos=?
where v_id_proteccion=?
    and v_cve_cliente=?")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicBeginTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatasourceAccessor.beginTransaction(DatasourceAccessor.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicBeginTransaction(AbstractSession.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.addWriteConnection(ClientSession.java:646)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.acquireClientConnection(ServerSession.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:216)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:728)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2863)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1501)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1483)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1457)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.executeUpdate(EJBQueryImpl.java:540)
    at com.telcel.gsa.dsiee.pprecios.amb_alt.FixProtsCv.updateCV(FixProtsCv.java:70)
    at com.telcel.gsa.dsiee.pprecios.amb_alt.FixProtsCv.fix(FixProtsCv.java:88)
    at com.telcel.gsa.dsiee.pprecios.amb_alt.FixProtsCv.main(FixProtsCv.java:42)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Transactions not supported
    at com.informix.util.IfxErrMsg.getSQLException(IfxErrMsg.java:348)
    at com.informix.jdbc.IfxSqliConnect.setAutoCommit(IfxSqliConnect.java:1333)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicBeginTransaction(DatabaseAccessor.java:223)
    ... 25 more
```

I have no problem doing the update using JDBC, ¿does JPA support Non-Transactional DB's?
For performance reasons the DBA has turned off transaction support on Informix, and that isn't going to change.
So, is there anything i'm missing? what's wrong?

P.D.
I have made the same update using a transaction-enabled Informix DB and it works.

Comment: Quietly twist the DBA's arms until he puts transactions back on the DB.  It is not sensible to work without transactions.

Comment: The errors you are getting look like consequences of trying to do transactions (BEGIN, COMMIT) on a DB without transactions. It is as if the `persistence.xml` description does not recognize the possiblility that there are no transactions. Standard (Informix-level) errors include: -255: Not in transaction (commit on transactional DB when no transaction active); -256: Transaction not available (begin or commit on non-transactional DB). How you go about resolving this I'm not sure. Using a transactional database would be best, but that seems to be a non-option. Gut feel: JPA won't work for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling transaction support is very odd.

With EclipseLink you can disable transaction using a SessionCustomizer,

```
session.getLogin().useExternalTransactionController();
```

This will make EclipseLink think something else in managing transactions (normally JTA), but in your case, nothing...

Answer (score 1):

The final working example (as suggested by James) is:

```
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("pp_pu");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

        Session session = em.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.getLogin().useExternalTransactionController();


        em.getTransaction().begin();
        int updates = em.createNamedQuery("CgEstatusEntity.updateById")
                .setParameter("iCveEstatus", 1)
                .setParameter("vDescEstatus", "Test9")
                .executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(updates);

        em.getTransaction().commit();

    }


}
```