# How do you use Spring Data JPA without Transaction?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, informix, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to use Spring Data JPA to access an Informix database. The database itself doesn't support Transactions. We are access the database through JDBC. The JDBC driver for Informix will throw error when you try to do anything transactional. getAutoCommit return true, and setting it false throws an error

The legacy code is using HibernateTemplate to access Informix. The service methods do not have any transactional annotations

I'm working a new project that access the same databases, and I wanted to try using Spring Data. Since, I want to continue using an ORM layer, I tried wiring up Spring Data JPA.

So, my initial configuration was

```
<bean id="emf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource"/>
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="org.company.project.business"/>
  <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
     <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">

     </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.InformixDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop>    
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_get_generated_keys">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.order_updates">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
     </props>
  </property>
</bean>
<bean id="datasource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
     destroy-method="close" depends-on="c3p0InformixConnectionCustomizer">
  <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="database"/>
  <property name="driverClass" value="com.informix.jdbc.IfxDriver"/>
  <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${database.jdbc.url}"/>
  <property name="user" value="${database.jdbc.user}"/>
  <property name="password" value="${database.jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>



<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
     class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

<jpa:repositories base-package="org.company.project.respository" entity-manager-factory-ref="emf"/>
```

Unfortunately, Spring data complains that I need a transaction manager. But, I don;t need a transaction manager! I don;t even need transactions

So, for shits and giggles, I declared the Jpa Transaction manager

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
      <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf"/>
</bean>
```

Obviously, Informix driver started complaining about not supporting transactions

SO, the question is how do I tell Spring Data not to use a transaction interceptor? I debugged through some of the calls, and all the calls to SimpleJPARepository have 4 interceptors wired into them. One of them is a TransactionInterceptor. Is there a way to tell Spring data not to wire up the interceptor?

---

What I ended up doing is implement a NullTransactionManager. Basically, a transaction manager that does nothing... just to give Spring Data something to chew on. Is there a better way? I would prefer to tell the factory that creates the repository to not wire up the interceptor.

```
public class NullTransactionManager implements PlatformTransactionManager
{
    public NullTransactionManager()
    {
        super();
    }

    public TransactionStatus getTransaction(TransactionDefinition pDefinition) throws TransactionException
    {
        // return a transaction status that doesn't do antyhing
        return new TransactionStatus() {
            public boolean isNewTransaction()
            {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean hasSavepoint()
            {
                return false;
            }

            public void setRollbackOnly()
            {
            }

            public boolean isRollbackOnly()
            {
                return false;
            }

            public void flush()
            {
            }

            public boolean isCompleted()
            {
                return false;
            }

            public Object createSavepoint()
            {
                return null;
            }

            public void rollbackToSavepoint(Object pSavepoint)
            {
            }

            public void releaseSavepoint(Object pSavepoint)
            {
            }
        };
    }

    public void commit(TransactionStatus pStatus) throws TransactionException
    {
        //do nothing
    }

    public void rollback(TransactionStatus pStatus) throws TransactionException
    {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of database doesn't support transactions? :) [I'm assuming this is your case](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs60/informix4/API_jinf4.html#647593). So you're running a non-ANSI, non logging database? Just out of curiosity, what is the benefit of having an Informix database configured that way?

Comment: If you were using EclipseLink as your JPA provider, [you could've used this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15661480/2408961)

Comment: Have you experimented with `hibernate.connection.autocommit` as [described here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch03.html#configuration-jdbc-properties)?

Comment: The database is a legacy database. It's not like we chose to use a 15 year old database on purpose. We are trying to get away from Informix, but because the system is so large, we have to take a phased approach. That means we will have to use Informix until we finish moving everything to JPA...I don;t think EclipseLink would have helped because it's the JPA Transaction Manager setting the autocommit. I have set hibernate.connection.autocommit to false as I menationed in the OP. It doesn't help

Comment: Ah ok, apologies, I didn't read your `jpaProperties` thoroughly. Seems your `NullTransactionManager` might be the only way then...

Answer (score 6):

You cannot - by definition - persist objects through JPA without a transaction. Section 7.9.1 of the specification clearly states that methods like `EntityManager.persist(…)` and `….merge(…)` require a transaction to be in progress.